# Multiple POST parameters, some containing XML

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'd Like to be able to have my web service accept multiple POST parameters, some of which will be XML. Is this possible?  The code below will generate a server error:

WebResponse resp = (WebResponse)req.GetResponse();

```
string programId = "1";
        string statusMessages = statusMessagesXML.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

```
    string postData = "programId=" + programId;
    postData += "&statusMessages=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(statusMessages);
    string data = postData;

    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    req.ContentLength = data.Length;
    req.Method = "POST";
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
    writer.Write(data);
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Close();

    String result = null;
    WebResponse resp = (WebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    Stream readstream = resp.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader read = new StreamReader(readstream);

    result = read.ReadToEnd();
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the server error? Also you mention that want to call a "web service", but this does not look like you are interacting with a WebService to me. Perhaps you just meant it in a generic HTTP sense?

Comment: Does it work when you pass the status message as simple string instead of XML?

Comment: Yes.  It appears that the < character causes the error.  If I pass "<abc" it'll error out.  If I pass ">abc" it's okay.  Also, it's a RESTful service, not a .NET SOAP web service.

Comment: did you tried to use:  request.ContentType = "text/xml"; ihave tried this but in sending only one paramter in an xml format by converting to bytes, but did not know how in multiple paramters

Answer (score -1):

The problem is:

```
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

This tells the server your data is URL-encoded, and '<' is a URL metacharacter. Either URLEncode your data, or don't tell the server the data is URLEncoded when it isn't.

Comment: HttpUtility.UrlEncode(statusMessages) above should be encoding it.